# Windows Phone camera customization

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-mobile

How can I use the camera in Windows Phone 10 and save screenshots o pictures with out flash (I mean blocking the flash option to the users) Is it possible?

Comment: Why you need th flash for screenshot or save pictures?

Comment: I want to take a screenshot of what the camera is aiming instead of taking a picture so I avoid flash use (when users have their camera setted to flash ON or on auto mode)

Comment: I think that you cannot do that. Because WP API doesn't allowed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the user experience you want making your own camera app. Universal Windows Platform APIs will give you full control over what your user will be able to do.

Take this sample camera app as a good starting point

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit

The process of taking a picture using the camera and taking a screenshot are completely different.

Answer (score 0):

here is an article on how to make and save a screenshot, works for win 8.1, also for Windows Phone 10
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lighthouse/archive/2013/10/18/capturing-snapshot-in-windows-8-1-store-app.aspx